# Jquery conditional regex return output

Tags: jquery, regex

Is it possible to use regex and jQuery to return conditional output, I would like to replace numbers surrounded by square brackets for images:

`[1]` would become `<span><img src="1.png"></span>`

where I have `[11]` it would replace it as

`<span><img src="1.png"><img src="1.png"></span>`

where I have `[1e1]` it would replace it as

`<span><img src="1.png"><img src="e.png"><img src="1.png"></span>`

However if it is only text it will leave as is regardless of length

`[qu]` would become `<span><img src="qu.png"></span>`

This is the code I have so far:

```
$('p').each(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();               
    var html = txt.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/g, function($1){

        if($1.length<=3) {
            return $1.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/g,'<span class=\'rehMark\'><img src="img/$1.png" alt="$1" /></span>')
        }else{

// this is the bit I would like help with!
// and how to deal with text rather than numbers

            return '<span class=\'lngRehMark\'>'

            for (i=0; i<$1.length; i++ )
            {
                return '<img src="img/' + $1 + '.png" alt="' + $1.length + '" /></span>'
            }
            return '</span'>'
        }
    });

    $(this).html(html);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split`, `map` and `join` to convert `[12]` to an array of `<img>` elements.

Also note that the first parameter of replace callback contains full matched string (e.g. `[11]`), not the first matched group (e.g. `11`).

```
$('p').each(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();               
    var html = txt.replace(/\[([^\]]*)\]/g, function(match, chars){
        var images;
        if (chars.match(/^[^0-9]*$/))
            images = '<img src="img/' + chars + '.png" />';
        else
            images = $(chars.split(''))
              .map(function() { return '<img src="img/' + this + '.png" />'; })
              .get().join('');
        return '<span class=\'lngRehMark\'>' + images + '</span>';
    });

    $(this).html(html);
});
```

Comment: I have multiple instances of the bracketed info e.g.'[4] to [5] ok' - this replaces everything between the first and last bracket, is there any way to modify it to do each instance?

Comment: Sure, I have fixed the code. Just replace "(.*)" with "([^]]*)" (match any character vs match any character except ']').

Comment: i've changed the code as you sugested - it now only matches where there is numerical and text values [1] is ignored but [1e] is changed, there will be a mix of the three [1],[dq],[3eq],[q3] would all be valid text to be replaced by images for each of the characters. thanks

Comment: @StephenGraham I am getting lost. What is the expected result for [12ab34ef]?

Comment: for each character between the square brackets a image would be returned

[1]  -  <span><img src="1.png"></span>  
[1e] - <span><img src="1.png"><img src="e.png"></span>  
[e2e] - <span><img src="e.png"><img src="2.png"><img src="e.png"></span>

Comment: @StephenGraham But then in your question you wrote that [qu] becomes one image? Now you are saying there should be two images. So for [12ab34ef] you are expecting 8 images, is that correct?

Comment: Yes 8 images, if the string is numerical or a mix of numbers and letters (e2e) then separate images (e.png & 2.png & e,png) HOWEVER if its just text (eq) it will be just one image (eq.png)

Comment: @StephenGraham Please check the current version, is it correct now? Could you please update the question and add these additional rules & examples there?